# Find MAX and SUM From Two Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am developing a point of sale system and in need of finding the customer who has the highest amount of purchase.

I have these two tables, the first which holds the customer and transaction number, the second holds the transaction number and the total amount of the transaction. Here is the table

```
--------------------------
| Customer | Transaction |
--------------------------
| 1000     | 902134      |
--------------------------
| 1001     | 798249      |
--------------------------
| 1001     | 312523      |
--------------------------
| 1002     | 741284      |
--------------------------
| 1000     | 122354      |
-------------------------- 

------------------------------
| Transaction | Total_Amount |
------------------------------
| 902134      | 9000.00      |
------------------------------
| 798249      | 3000.00      |
------------------------------
| 312523      | 5000.00      |
------------------------------
| 741284      | 4000.00      |
------------------------------
| 122354      | 1000.00      |
------------------------------
```

I need to get the customer code 1000 which has 10,000.00 worth of transaction.

I am using MySQL and PHP.

Comment: it is unclear from the question exactly you want to SUM and find the MAX value for.

Comment: Have you written a query? Can you post it?

Comment: Together with an answer this would make the perfect material for a school book about Mysql. Which brings me to the point, that such training material already exists. For these basic topics, please do your own research first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will  retrieve customers that have the same *total* `transaction_amount` and which is (*possibly*) the highest total amount value of across all customers.

```
SELECT aa.customer, SUM(bb.Total_AMount) GrandTotal
FROM    tableCustomer aa
        LEFT JOIN tabletransaction bb
            ON aa.`Transaction` = bb.`Transaction`
GROUP BY aa.customer
HAVING SUM(bb.Total_AMount) =
(
    SELECT MAX(totalSum)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  SUM(b.Total_AMount) totalSUM
        FROM    tableCustomer a
                LEFT JOIN tableTransaction b
                    ON a.`Transaction` = b.`Transaction`
        GROUP BY a.customer
    ) x
)
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4081/10)
- [**SQLFiddle Demo** (*With the same highest total Amount*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b59a/2)

Comment: +1 for nice solution without sorting

Comment: Thanks! This just works!